# Cannot add line specific comment to Json files for code reviews in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am performing a code review in Visual Studio 2015 version 14.0.25431 Update 3 with TFS 2015 Update 3. With all files with the exception of Json files, I can make line specific comments; that is, I can highlight a piece of code, right click and add a comment. With Json files, when I right click, the option is not present. I can add file level comments to all files; that is, I can right click a file in my Code Review panel and add a comment.

Additional information: I see a banner when I open files from the Code Review panel that says "Read-only comparison view. You can add comments by selecting code to comment on, right clicking and choosing Add Comment". However, this appears when I open any files, and not specifically Json files.

Comment: Same issue in VS 2017, works in 2012